# Is outputting to both a result set and a temporary table possible?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, temporary-tables

I have a stored procedure that I need to both output the result set to the user and use a piece of information in the result set to possibly output other result sets.

Here is a basic schema of what I have

```
create table FooQueue(FooId int, IsQueued bit)
create table Foo(FooId int primary key, BarId int, FooData varchar(50))

create table BarQueue(BarId int, IsQueued bit)
create table Bar(BarId int primary key, BarData varchar(50)
```

Here is a very simplified version of the stored procedures.

```
create procedure GetFoos as
begin
    select FooId, FooData 
    from Foo 
    where FooId in (select FooId from FooQueue where IsQueued = 1)

    update BarQueue 
    set IsQueued = 1 
    where BarId in (select BarId 
                    from Foo 
                    where FooId in (select FooId from FooQueue where  IsQueued = 1))

    exec GetBars

    delete FooQueue where IsQueued = 1
end
GO

create procedure GetBars as
begin
    select BarId, BarData 
    from Bar 
    where BarId in (select BarId from BarQueue where IsQueued = 1)

    delete Bar where IsQueued = 1
end
GO
```

And the first procedure is called like the following

```
update top 10000 Foo set IsQueued = 1
exec GetFoos
```

I am about to modify a large number of the stored procedures so it does not hit the `Foo` table twice to something like the following

```
alter procedure GetFoos as
begin
    select FooId, BarId, FooData 
    from Foo
    into #t
    where FooId in (select FooId from FooQueue where IsQueued = 1)

    select FooId, FooData from #t

    update BarQueue 
    set IsQueued = 1 
    where BarId in (select BarId from #t)

    exec GetBars

    delete FooQueue where IsQueued = 1
end
GO
```

Would this be the correct approach to doing this or is there a better way to both return the resultset (without `BarId` included) and update the 2nd table based on the returned rows?

Comment: you will not need second Select statement after insert. check the OUTPUT CLAUSE. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

you can alter the column in select or insert list as you need.

```
    alter procedure GetFoos as
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE #t (FooId INT, BarId INT, FooData SYSNAME)

        select FooId, BarId, FooData 
        OUTPUT INSERTED.FooId, INSERTED.BarId,INSERTED.FooData INTO #t(FooId, BarId, FooData )
        from Foo
        where FooId in (select FooId from FooQueue where IsQueued = 1)

        update BarQueue 
        set IsQueued = 1 
        where BarId in (select BarId from #t)

        exec GetBars

        delete FooQueue where IsQueued = 1
    end
    GO
```

Answer (score -1):

Not looked calmly yet, but depending on the situation, this is a good way to do what you need.

But as a suggestion to make this way will help to optimize the process and review your data model to better serve tasks like this.

```
alter procedure GetFoos 
as 

begin

select t1.FooId, t1.BarId, t1.FooData 
from Foo t1 , FooQueue t2
into #t
where t1.FooId = t2.FooId
and t2.IsQueued = 1

select FooId, FooData from #t

update BarQueue 
set IsQueued = 1 
where BarId exists (select BarId from #t)

exec GetBars

delete FooQueue where IsQueued = 1
end
GO
```

Comment: Your change changes the output, `FooId` on FooQueue is not constrained to be unique so your version will now cause duplicate records to be returned. The select would need to be `select distinct FooId, FooData from #t` to get the same behavior as my original query.